# Retrieve LeadSource, Leadrating using Apex

Tags: c#, apex

I am integrating Salesforce in to my ASP.NET aplication. I am trying retrieve the default lead Source, lead rating and industry from users account. If I am using SOQL query like "select LeadSOurce from Lead" then it is giving me the leads record from the inserted leads only but I want the default entry that leadsource contains the value and Text in drop down. Please suggest me how can I retrieve the values using SOQL or by using APEX code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please help me its really very urgent. I am still Searching for the result.

Comment: One option is the metadata API - see http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_picklist.htm; you can't get default picklist value from SOQL.  The Apex equivalent of the metadata API is Schema.Describe which is well documented in the APEX Developers guide.